The covering number of a d-dim cube
In Martin Wainwright's textbook, equation (5.5) states that the $\delta$-covering number of the d-dimensional cube satisfies
$$
\log N(\delta; [0,1]^d) \asymp d \log(\frac{1}{\delta}),
$$
for small enough $\delta$, $N(\delta,A)$ is the $\delta$-covering number of the set $A$.
The question I have is, what exactly is the meaning of $\asymp$ here?
Can anyone provide me an example of $A \asymp B$ and the definition of $\asymp$?
Unfortunately, Wainwright did not include a table of notation in his book.

$A\asymp B$ means there are constants $c$ and $C$ such that $cA<B<CA$: it's a symmetric form of big-O.
